# How to expand all PrimeNG treeTable fastly?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I'm using PrimeNG treeTable in my Angular app. And the treeTable data is very large. Every item has more than 200 items.

Here is what it looks like :

```
{
    "data":
    [  
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Documents",
                "size":"75kb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Work",
                        "size":"55kb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Expenses.doc",
                                "size":"30kb",
                                "type":"Document"
                            }
                        },
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Resume.doc",
                                "size":"25kb",
                                "type":"Resume"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"Home",
                        "size":"20kb",
                        "type":"Folder"
                    },
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "data":{  
                                "name":"Invoices",
                                "size":"20kb",
                                "type":"Text"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Pictures",
                "size":"150kb",
                "type":"Folder"
            },
            "children":[  
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"barcelona.jpg",
                        "size":"90kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"primeui.png",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "data":{  
                        "name":"optimus.jpg",
                        "size":"30kb",
                        "type":"Picture"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

my  function is this. I want to expand all . I use recursion. **But it spent a lot of time.**

**So do you have a better algorithm？**

```
 expandAll(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.expand(e.node.children);
  }


  expand(element) {
    element.forEach(element => {
      element.expanded = true;
      this.expand(element.children);
    });
  }
}

 <p-treeTable[value]="treedataList" (onNodeExpand) = "expandAll($event)"></p-treeTable>
```

**Here is PrimeNG treetable link:**
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable

Comment: Are you really using PrimeFaces? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0):

You can include expand as a property of node item like this:

```
{  
    "data":{  
        "name":"Home",
        "size":"20kb",
        "type":"Folder"
    },
    "children":[  
        {  
            "data":{  
                "name":"Invoices",
                "size":"20kb",
                "type":"Text"
            },
            expanded: true
        }
    ],
    expanded: true
}
```

Tree table uses the following node interface:

```
export interface TreeNode {
    data?: any;
    children?: TreeNode[];
    leaf?: boolean;
    expanded?: boolean;
}
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable